# Laravel whereHas eloqvent relation

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to get object from table orders with related attributes from table order_status_history. From table order_status_history, i need only last record with status 'Reviewing', so i use sort asc by field created_at. My code so far is , but i get error.

```
$orders = Order::GetOrderHistoryReviewing()->get();

 public function scopeGetOrderHistoryReviewing($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('statusHistory', function($q) {

           $q->where('status', 'Reviewing')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();

        });
    }
```

i need one object with relation from second table

this is my error

```
[2016-07-27 08:37:26] dev.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "orders"
LINE 1: ...ries" where "order_status_histories"."order_id" = "orders"."...
```

Comment: So what is your question? You mentioned an error but I don't see any errors in your post. If you want help you'll need to provide more information, the text from the errors you're getting, what you've tried so far to fix it etc.

Comment: i think with first isnt working i get query error

Comment: Great, you still haven't told us the error. Copy the exact words the error gives you and update your question with them...

Comment: this is my error [2016-07-27 08:37:26] dev.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "orders"
LINE 1: ...ries" where "order_status_histories"."order_id" = "orders"."...

Comment: Simply remove the the `first()` call. That's used to actually run the query but a scope is meant for filtering results from a database query.

Comment: yes but how to get only one record sorted by desc

Comment: Just added an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you're apparently trying to create a scope that returns orders with status, 'Reviewing' and sorts the results in descending order.

You need to remove the `first()` call from the `$q` subquery and move `orderBy` to the end of your `$query`. Your code should look like.

```
public function scopeGetOrderHistoryReviewing($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('statusHistory', function($q) {

       $q->where('status', 'Reviewing');

    })->orderBy('created_at','desc');
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$orders = Order::GetOrderHistoryReviewing()->get();
//OR to get the first record
$first_order = Order::GetOrderHistoryReviewing()->first();
```

Comment: but i need first record from statusHistory order by desc not table Orders

Comment: Then you can use `orderBy('statusHistory.created_at', 'desc')` instead :)

Comment: but i will not get first record